# Associating arbitrary data with COM thread context

Tags: .net, com

Okay. This is a terrible question. And it's about old stuff. So, good luck I guess.

I am dealing with a situation where I am doing some pretty heavy interop between .NET, VB6 COM objects, and Classic ASP in IIS. I am trying to devise a solution to make a .NET object available to threads in .NET which originate THROUGH a COM object. Thread local storage that is available from within .NET, and is associated with a call stack when that call stack enters .NET from COM interop.

For instance, some client code would retrieve a reference to the COM object from a service which attaches some stuff. Then the client code would call into the COM object. The COM object would then call into the .NET object. And from .NET I could get that attached stuff. Like TLS all the way through.

More crazy version: I'm retrieving COM objects from a DI container in .Net. I'd like to attach something to those COM objects, so that when they call back into .NET, I know from what container they originated from.

COM is weird. And has lots of things I am probably not aware of. For instance, Enterprise Services. And contexts. And weird transaction scope stuff. And .NET is also weird, so maybe I could do it on something in the CCW that makes the data available. Or maybe I can wrap the .NET object in a proxy and hand the proxy to COM. Ooh. That last one sounds promising. I wonder if I can create a dynamic .NET proxy, and then marshal it to COM as the original interface.

Can I do that?

Anyways, please weigh in.

Comment: With Enterprise Services (=Component Services), COM object are wrapped in "contexts". These contexts can have properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/comsvcs/nn-comsvcs-icontextproperties). From .NET this is available through ContextUtil: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enterpriseservices.contextutil.setnamedproperty?view=netframework-4.7.2 Not sure what's your after exactly, but it's worth a try

Comment: So this only works for various intrinsic objects I've found. Stuff added by either MTS or IIS. If I could add my own, we might be onto something.

Answer (score 0):

If all your COM objects are written in VB6 then they are all single threaded. As a STA has only one thread and all calls to an object in that STA will be marshalled to that thread.

If you create an adaptor that wraps the VB6 object, including doing its creation, and your adaptor is also single threaded then it will always be on the same thread as the VB6 object. Accessing thread local storage from the adaptor will match the thread local storage of the VB6 object.

Note, VB6 code can use thread local storage as well but that would mean finding the correct code to call the necessary Win32 methods for an obsolete platform.

Comment: @wasabi "single threaded apartment": it is the same thing (I tend to call it single because it emphasises the most significant attribute :-) ).